# Greedy graph coloring

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

For taking part in a course, I need to learn some Java. Unfortunately they only teach Java 1.6, so I understand that later versions could simplify the below code a lot, but I have to stick with 1.6 though, at least for the course.

I have zero prior knowledge of Java, in order to prepare for the course, I implemented a simple greedy algorithm for coloring a simple graph based on a given adjacency list. Any comments for improving the code are welcome, but please keep in mind it has to be compatible with Java version 1.6.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Graph {
    final private static int UNCOLORED = -1;

    private int maxDegree = 0;
    private Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> edges = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>();
    private Map<Integer, Integer> nodesSortedByDegree;

    Graph(Map<Integer, int[]> adjacencyList) {
        initialize(adjacencyList);
    }

    private void initialize(Map<Integer, int[]> adjacencyList) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> degrees = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, int[]> entry : adjacencyList.entrySet()) {
            int node = entry.getKey();
            int[] neighbors = entry.getValue();

            // calculate degree for node
            int degree = degrees.getOrDefault(node, 0);
            int newDegree = degree + neighbors.length;

            if (newDegree > maxDegree) {
                maxDegree = newDegree;
            }

            degrees.put(node, newDegree);

            for (int i = 0; i < neighbors.length; i++) {
                int neighbor = neighbors[i];

                // calculate degree for neighbors
                degree = degrees.getOrDefault(neighbor, 0);
                newDegree = degree + 1;

                if (newDegree > maxDegree) {
                    maxDegree = newDegree;
                }

                degrees.put(neighbor, newDegree);

                // add edge from/to node and neighbor
                edges.putIfAbsent(node, new HashSet<Integer>());
                edges.get(node).add(neighbor);

                edges.putIfAbsent(neighbor, new HashSet<Integer>());
                edges.get(neighbor).add(node);
            }
        }

        nodesSortedByDegree = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(new MapValuesComparator(degrees));
        nodesSortedByDegree.putAll(degrees);
    }

    public Map<Integer,Integer> greedyColoring() {
        int maxColors = maxDegree + 1;
        System.out.printf("# We can color G using at most %d colors.\n", maxColors);

        Map<Integer, Integer> coloring = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        BitSet used = new BitSet(maxColors);

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : nodesSortedByDegree.entrySet()) {
            int node = entry.getKey();
            Set<Integer> neighbors = edges.get(node);

            // color neighbors first
            for (Integer neighbor : neighbors) {
                int neighborColor = coloring.getOrDefault(neighbor, UNCOLORED);

                if (neighborColor == UNCOLORED) {
                    int nextColor = used.nextClearBit(0);
                    coloring.put(neighbor, nextColor);

                    used.flip(nextColor);
                } else {
                    used.flip(neighborColor);
                }
            }

            // then assign the first left over color to node
            int nodeColor = used.nextClearBit(0);
            coloring.put(node, nodeColor);

            used.clear();
        }

        return coloring;
    }
}

public class Main {
    final private static String[] COLORS = new String[] {
            "red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "black",
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, int[]> adjacencyList = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>();
        adjacencyList.put(1, new int[]{2});
        adjacencyList.put(2, new int[]{1, 3});
        adjacencyList.put(3, new int[]{4, 5});

        Graph g = new Graph(adjacencyList);
        Map<Integer, Integer> coloring = g.greedyColoring();

        dumpColoring(coloring);
    }

    private static void dumpColoring(Map<Integer, Integer> coloring) {
        System.out.println("=====================");

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e : coloring.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("# Color %d in %s\n", e.getKey(), COLORS[e.getValue()]);
        }
    }
}

class MapValuesComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    private Map<Integer, Integer> m;

    public MapValuesComparator(Map<Integer, Integer> m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        int compare = m.get(b).compareTo(m.get(a));

        if (compare == 0) {
            return 1;
        }

        return compare;
    }
}
```

The program roughly works like this:

- Build a list with edges in both directions from the given adjacency list.
- Compute max. degree to find out how much colors we need to use at most.
- Sort vertices by degree.

The actual coloring:

- iterates the vertices sorted by degree.
- colors all neighbors and the node itself.

The output should be sth like:

```
# We can color G using at most 4 colors.
=====================
# Color 1 in red
# Color 2 in blue
# Color 3 in yellow
# Color 4 in red
# Color 5 in red
```

Comment: Haha no one want's to have a look at my java code from the stoneage. Maybe it's a bit unreasonable constraint to expect people to review outdated code … let's me also doubt a bit for what kind of course I signed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason more seems to be that the code doesn't need much improvement.

Some minor remarks from my side:

1. The following of your statements are actually not compatible with Java 1.6: `Map.getOrDefault` and `Map.putIfAbsent`. You can verify this by looking at the JavaDoc expression `@since 1.8`.
2. Use a logger instead of `System.out.println` if you're implementing more than just quick and dirty demo code.
3. The [Java Style Guidelines](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~alundblad/styleguide/index-v6.html#toc-modifiers) recommend that `final` should go after `private static`
4. You can use for-each loops on primitive arrays to eliminate the need for non-describing variables such as `i`: `for (final int neighbor : neighbors) {`
5. Try to have only one top-level class per file in real projects.

Comment: Thank you! Solid feedback, I didn't know it's also possible to use for-each on the primitive arrays.